# Where can I find arrivals / departures timetables for Italian train stations online?

Tags: trains, public-transport, online-resources, italy, trenitalia

**I am looking for a place where I can find the arrivals / departures timetables for all Italian train stations** (or at least the ones served by Trenitalia & Italo). Ideally a pdf of those paper arrival / departures timetables that you find in the stations. See [this image](http://www.stazionidelmondo.it/spoleto31.JPG) if you don't know what I mean.

This information is all public since I could search it via Trenitalia queries and surely a pdf of something must exist to print the timetables that are hanging in the stations. I was able to find [something similar for Roma Termini](http://www.thetrainline-europe.com/station/roma-termini~8300263) but that site only covers a few major stations and not the ones I am looking for. It is also confusing to navigate.

I know I could look at the trip planner of Trenitalia or similar sites but for the trip planning I wish to do these timetables would just be more convenient.

Comment: In Italy, train schedules are merely a suggestion anyway. =)

Comment: The trenìt mobile app might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This site (rfi.it)](http://www.rfi.it/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=7fa6d0b61d40a410VgnVCM1000008916f90aRCRD) gives arrivals and departures in a form similar to what I think you are expecting.

Sample output for Roma Termini:

[image]

There's also a list of regional timetables in PDF format here:
http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom/Informazioni/Orari-regionali-in-versione-pdf

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had a good look on the [Trenitalia site](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom), both in the [English version](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom-en) and in the google translate version of the original to my own language, (Dutch) and did not find any links or other indications of 'per station' listings.

But I did find [this page, which promises times per line](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom/Informazioni/Orario-ferroviario) rather than per station.
If like me you do not read Italian, you will need a translation service to work out what to click, this is what the site tells you:

> Grazie a questo strumento, una volta salvato sul tuo PC, potrai consultare gli orari anche offline.

Which translates to (with thanks to google)

> With this tool, once saved on your PC, you can check timetables even offline.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this through the Czech [IDOS website](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/vlaky/odjezdy/). Simply enter the name of the station in the `From` field, after switching the language in the bottom-right corner.

[image]

Optionally choose the date and click on `SEARCH`. You'll get the full list of trains departing from each of Rome's train stations:

[image]

Clicking on an individual train will show you it's full schedule:

[image]

Unfortunately this only works for Trenitalia trains. For Italo trains, an [official timetable](http://www.italotreno.it/~/media/Images/content/pdf/orari/italo_orari_eng.pdf) is available from [their website](http://www.italotreno.it/en/destinations-timetable).

Comment: That is neat, great! Button to change to English is on the bottom right and timetable is per day and hour and easily navigatable! +1 and thanks!